# How to fix Contact form 7 get parameters(utm)?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, utm

Something wrong with utm source parameter. That's the form(translated)

```
<div class="popup__input-container d-flex flex-column"><div class="d-flex flex-column"><h3 class="popup__title">Leave a request</h3>[text* form-name-1 class:phone__input-popup placeholder "Name"][tel* form-number-1 class:phone__input-popup placeholder "Your phone number"]

<div hidden>
[text utm_source default:get]
[text utm_medium default:get]
[text utm_campaign default:get]
[text utm_term default:get]
[text utm_content default:get]
</div>

[submit class:phone__button "Send"]<span class="popup__close" id="popUpClose">Close</span></div></div>
```

That's the part for email

```
Name: [form-name-1]
Phone number: [form-number-1]

Sent from url: [_url]
UTM source: [utm_source]
UTM medium: [utm_medium]
UTM campaign: [utm_campaign]
UTM term: [utm_term]
UTM term:[utm_content]
```

When I make a fake get-parameters in my string, all works fine - utm are the same as from [_url]
But when someone else really comes from advs url and leaves the request, the [_url] can contain

```
https://example.com/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=conversion&fbclid=IwAR1lHKi82HKpBMM74YxOJjxQfHXWZ3mzLqm93H2YD9JeLTaRzpf-87XNDxE
```

But

```
UTM source: google
```

It's not a one-time issue, there are few such issues in letters.
What's this and why? Where I made a mistake in setings?